# simple-spreadsheet not properly loading an xls file on ruby, but working properly on irb

Tags: ruby, excel, rubygems, spreadsheet, irb

I'm currently trying to open and parse [this xls file](http://app.sofofa.cl/indicadores/archiv_indicad/Agrupaciones/151.xls) using ruby 2.1.1. The straightforward way would be to use the simple-spreadsheet gem, which doesn't seem to work properly for this particular spreadsheet (and a couple others):

```
require 'simple-spreadsheet'
s=SimpleSpreadsheet::Workbook.read('151.xls')
puts s.last_row #prints 5
```

However, when I copy and paste this exact code into irb, I get the right answer

```
2.1.1 :001 > require 'simple-spreadsheet'
 => true 
2.1.1 :002 > s=SimpleSpreadsheet::Workbook.read('151.xls')
 => #prints the entire contents of the spreadsheet
2.1.1 :003 > s.last_row
 => 154
```

The same behaviour occurs when using Roo (which is to be expected, as simple-spreadsheet uses Roo to open .xls files):

```
require 'roo'
s=Roo::Excel.new('151.xls')
puts s.last_row #prints 5, should print 154
```

While on irb

```
2.1.1 :001 > require 'simple-spreadsheet'
 => true 
2.1.1 :002 > s=Roo::Excel.new('151.xls')
 => #prints the entire contents of the spreadsheet
2.1.1 :003 > s.last_row
 => 154
```

Digging further, I tried using spreadsheet, as it is required on Roo's excel.rb file:

```
require 'spreadsheet'    
Spreadsheet.open('151.xls') do |book|
  rows=0
  book.worksheet(0).each do |row|
    rows+=1
  end
  puts rows#prints 5
end
```

However, this is where it gets weird(er); when I copy and paste this last code into irb, I get

```
2.1.1 :001 > require 'spreadsheet'    
 => true 
2.1.1 :002 > Spreadsheet.open('152.xls') do |book|
2.1.1 :003 >       rows=0
2.1.1 :004?>     book.worksheet(0).each do |row|
2.1.1 :005 >           rows+=1
2.1.1 :006?>       end
2.1.1 :007?>     puts rows
2.1.1 :008?>   end
5
 => nil
```

I should probably add that the gems aren't just printing 5; every cell below this row returns nil; they actually stop parsing the file after this particular row.

So here are my questions: fist, why is irb behaving differently than ruby? Secondly, why isn't any of those gems loading the entire spreadsheet? Third, what can I do to fix this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you confirm which version of rubyzip you're using? I was trying with 0.9.9 and was getting results consistent with what you mentioned, but just wanted to be sure. I noticed the newest version of rubyzip breaks simple-spreadsheet.

Comment: I have rubyzip 1.1.2 and 0.9.9. When reading xlsx files I have to add the line "gem 'rubyzip', '< 1.0.0'" before requiring simple-spreadsheet or the script breaks when trying to load the spreadsheet, but that doesn't seem to be the case with xls files. Is there a way to check which version of rubyzip is actually being loaded?

Comment: Looks like you can do `Gem.loaded_specs['rubyzip'].version` within a program / within irb. Make sure you do the appropriate require first (eg - `require 'simple-spreadsheet'`)

Comment: simple-spreadsheet and roo load rubyzip 0.9.9, both when running ruby from the console and within irb. However, spreadsheet doesn't load rubyzip at all.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at this yesterday and it does in seem like a really strange issue, particularly the differences between the ruby program and irb behavior. Could you possibly make a copy of the spreadsheet, but with fewer lines (say 20 instead of 154) and see if it still has the same behavior? If it does still only read the first 5 lines, having a smaller file will decrease the debug time drastically.

Comment: Even though I was a bit late (since you already answered my question), I deleted a few rows off of the excel and left only 17 (so now the right output should be 17 in all cases) and uploaded it [here](http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/514734/151-xls.html). However, it still takes almost a minute to load and parse when using inspect, while other spreadsheets take just a few seconds at most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the strangest issues I've ever seen. To answer your questions:

**First, why is irb behaving differently than ruby?**

IRB is a tool that is written in ruby, and is different than executing ruby directly. One of the main differences is that IRB has different options that can be set on startup. You can see the different flags in the [source](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/lib/irb.rb), and [this page](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/irb.html) has some good descriptions of what those flags mean.

The culprit for the inconsistencies you're seeing is the `--noinspect` option, run `irb --noinspect` and executing your code should give you the same strange behavior as running the ruby program (where you only see 5 rows). This is because irb defaults to calling inspect on every line that's executed, so when you call `s=SimpleSpreadsheet::Workbook.read('151.xls')` it's actually like calling this in a ruby program:

```
s = SimpleSpreadsheet::Workbook.read('151.xls')
s.inspect
```

Why does calling `s.inspect` matter? Keep reading...

**Secondly, why isn't any of those gems loading the entire spreadsheet?**

This is the hardest question to answer, I still haven't pinpointed it 100%, but hopefully the 90% explanation is good enough. In short, all of the gems you mention rely on the `spreadsheet` gem. One of the quirks/bugs of that gem in this particular setup (I don't think it's designed to always work like this) seems to be its reliance on the `inspect` method. If you call `inspect` on the worksheet it is persisting more values than if you don't call it. That is to say, if you don't call `inspect` on it's only reading part of the file (or reading some of it and disregarding the rest, I'm not sure) but if you do call `inspect` it reads the file entirely.

**Third, what can I do to fix this?**

As I alluded to before, manually calling `inspect` should read the entire file:

```
s = SimpleSpreadsheet::Workbook.read('151.xls')
s.inspect
```

Comment: This is insane, how did you figure this out? Please let me know if you actually pinpoint the issue, but it probably has something to do with why the gem takes so long to read the spreadsheet when compared to others of similar size. I finally wrote the same code in python, which takes a few seconds to download and parse about 50 spreadsheets, while ruby is taking over 50 seconds to parse just one spreadsheet. Should I open a ticket with the maintainers of spreadsheet?

Comment: I had originally tried to debug the 2 versions side by side (ruby program vs running the code in irb). This didn't get me anywhere so eventually I lucked out when researching how irb works.

Comment: You're right in that the code seems to be slow, I suspect that's an issue with `simple-spreadsheet` [depending on an old version](https://github.com/zenkay/simple-spreadsheet/blob/master/Gemfile.lock#L7) of the `spreadsheet` gem (0.6.5.9). You could submit an issue to request to have it updated, but since `simple-spreadsheet` just references other gems, I would probably ditch it in favor of `roo` which uses a newer version of spreadsheet.

Comment: I also see you've [submitted an issue with spreadsheet](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/issues/93), which was the other thing I was going to suggest :)